# How can I visually simulate a button being clicked with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that was suggested to me earlier today:

```
$(window).keypress(function (e)
{
  if (e.keyCode == 13)
  {
      $('#doCheck').focus().click();
   }
});
```

One user in another post said that this would make a button appear to animate and be clicked. When I tried it does have some effect but at least in Firefox it still does not make the button appear as though it's being clicked. Has anyone been able to make a button look like it's physically clicked with jQuery?

Comment: Are you trying to make it look like it's being clicked without the user actually clicking on it, or just making a button look like it "clicks" when a user does actually click on it?

Answer (score 2):

On execution, you would need to switch classes to make the button look pressed, then you would need to setInterval for a few milliseconds and once fired change the class back to a regular looking button.

Comment: I can change classes easily as there is some server call between the press and the completion. The server call takes maybe 1/2 second. My problem is how to change the class to make it look like a real button press. I guess every browser is different and I would like a way that works for all.

Answer (score 1):

just change the border...an unclicked button generally has an outset border, when you click it, it changes to inset so:

```
$(window).keydown(function (e)
{
  if (e.keyCode == 13)
  {
      $('#doCheck').css({borderStyle:'inset'});
   }
});
$(window).keyup(function (e)
{
  if (e.keyCode == 13)
  {
      $('#doCheck').css({borderStyle:'outset'});
      $('#doCheck').focus().click();
   }
});
```

Comment: I tried this but at least in Firefox the button doesn't look the same with a border style as outset. It's square and lost all it's character :-(

Comment: The problem is that when you start changing the style of an input button the default style is discarded, your best bet is to create your own css rules for buttons. That would allow you to ensure they looked and acted the same in all browsers, then you can just switch out the class with the same keyup/down methods